Can a "sharp turn" on a trace with an SMD resistor also present a risk of reflection?
I'm aware that in transmission lines, taking sharp 90-degree angle turns are a bad idea. Below is an example of different current behaviors of high-speed transmission lines from various shapes of traces.

(Image from a white paper from Simberian Inc.: How Interconnects Work: Minimal-reflection 90-degree bends in strip lines)
Could an SMD resistor (or even capacitor), cause the same issue if we have our trace as such?

(Made this picture on my own)
Would it be better if the trace was properly shaped before/after it goes into/out of the resistor?

(Made this picture on my own)

what frequencies are you operating at, and what size of resistors are we talking about? Note the figures cited have traces that are < 0.25mm wide and the observed frequency is 10 GHz.

@MarcusMüller Thanks for the response. I have various 1005 (metric, not imperial) 0-ohm resistors. I'd rather not attenuate the signal too much with high impedance but they're there to allow interface options. Therefore, frequencies can range from 1MHz to 1GHz.

yeah, then, don't really worry? at 1 GHz, the chip's width is possibly within the width of your microstrip line, and will mostly just look like a short piece of microstrip line slightly higher above the reference plane than it should. The main obstacle to conducting RF here will be how this wider component gets matched to the trace, and the RF properties of the resistor itself.


Could an SMD resistor (or even capacitor), cause the same issue if we
have our trace as such?

Yes it could, but only at speeds of 100GHz+ (1/20th wavelength is 6mm which is about the sizes of larger SMT components), I don't think that there would be any difference as their simulations suggest below 1GHz, so something is wrong with their simulation.
Another difference is in the cross capacitance of the trace which would be a few femptoFarads which wouldn't really make a difference and even if you were working with signals fast enough even how much the solder would start to make a difference if you were worried about details such as this.

Would it be better if the trace was properly shaped before/after it
goes into/out of the resistor?

Doesn't matter for most normal applications, if you were designing something above 5GHz the simulator could tell you what would be best, because the other components around it would matter.

Yes it certainly could - but so would the trace ending up with resistor pad as well.
For high speed design, you need to determine  how large an effect something has in order to determine if it is signficant enough that it matters in your case or insignificant enough that it does not matter in your case.
Sometimes you may need to remove ground layer under resistor pad to make it less capacitive or exhibit less impedance drop.
If the frequencies of 1 GHz are digital signals at 1 Gbps, the actual analog square wave signal has many harmonics of 1 GHz, depending on the digital signal, it may require 5 or 10 GHz of analog bandwidth to be able to pass a 1 Gbps digital signal successfully within specs of some data transfer protocol.
